# How to read the stored procedure return value in mule CE?

Tags: mule, mule-studio

Below is the code to execute stored procedure but not able to catch the return value in Payload. Please Advise how can we catch and print the stored procedure return value.

```
<jdbc:outbound-endpoint queryKey="InsertRecords"connector-ref="DBConnector" doc:name="InsertRecords (Deprecated)"
              exchange-pattern="request-response" queryTimeout="-1">
    <jdbc:transaction action="NONE"></jdbc:transaction>
    <jdbc:query key="InsertRecords" value="call InsertUserRecords('Test', 'Test')"></jdbc:query>
</jdbc:outbound-endpoint>
```

Comment: Please let me know if we have a solution to this? Thank you.